# Mongodb Schemas for different types of Posts/Articles

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm developing an application with Mongodb, Mongoose and Expressjs in which there are articles or posts of different types. For example there's URL post which only includes of a URL or address and doesn't have text inside of it. There's normal posts, Map posts, Image posts and bunch of other types.

Now I want to define the schema of `Post`s in my Application. I'm a bit confused if I should be defining different schemas for each of these since they should have different attributes and properties when they share some properties or, put all possible properties inside the `Post` schema and use an attribute with the name of `type` to specify the type of the post that's been shared.

What's the best practice to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your needs. If you want to run queries on the whole `Post` collection that can result different types of posts you should use one common schema with a `type` attribute. If not, go with the separate collections, that makes the system clear and easy to understand.

If you think of use one collection and there are common attributes in each schema you should try the `mongoose-schema-extend` package. With this you can handle your schemas like classes and do an inheritance.

https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting all common attributes in one schema and let your posts be of dynamic type (e.g. your posts could have images as well as text and videos). And you could end up with something like this:

```
post {
  (_)id : ...,
  user_id: ...,
  .
  .
  .
},
post_images{
  (_)id:...,
  post_id:...,
  uri:...,
  .
  .
  .
}
```